# Combining generator for different datatypes in Quickcheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I would like to combine two custom generators of different data type, but which are grouped together in another datatype.

In the following example, I would like to use the generator for `Legumes` and `AnimalProteins` to create another one for Proteins. `choose` and `elements` does not work as the type are different. Casting the generators as `gen Proteins` does not work either.

```
data AnimalProteins = Beef | Chicken | Fish
data Legumes = WhiteBeans | RedBeans | Lentils | Chickpeas

data Proteins = AnimalProteins | Legumes deriving (Show)

rAnimalProteins :: Gen AnimalProteins
rAnimalProteins = elements [Beef , Chicken , Fish]

rLegumes :: Gen Legumes
rLegumes = elements [WhiteBeans , RedBeans , Lentils , Chickpeas]

-- This does not work !
rProteins :: Gen Proteins
rProteins = choose (rLegumes, rAnimalProteins)
```

The solution may be simple but I'm quite stuck here as a beginner. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you intend to model `Proteins` as a choice between `AnimalProteins` and `Legumes`, you probable need something like this instead:

```
data AnimalProteins = Beef | Chicken | Fish deriving (Show, Eq)
data Legumes = WhiteBeans | RedBeans | Lentils | Chickpeas deriving (Show, Eq)

data Proteins = AP AnimalProteins | L Legumes deriving (Show, Eq)
```

You can combine generators like this:

```
rAnimalProteins :: Gen AnimalProteins
rAnimalProteins = elements [Beef, Chicken, Fish]

rLegumes :: Gen Legumes
rLegumes = elements [WhiteBeans, RedBeans, Lentils, Chickpeas]

rProteins :: Gen Proteins
rProteins = oneof [fmap AP rAnimalProteins, fmap L rLegumes]
```

The `rAnimalProteins` and `rLegumes` are as you've already defined them. You can 'lift' them into two separate `Gen Proteins` values with `fmap`, since `Gen` is a `Functor`.

For example, `fmap AP rAnimalProteins` maps the `Gen Legumes` value to a `Gen Proteins` value by mapping every generated `Legumes` value by wrapping it with the `AP` data constructor. While it's a `Gen Proteins` value, it'll always create `AP` values, that is, either `AP Beef`, `AP Chicken`, or `AP Fish`.

Likewise, `fmap L rLegumes` lifts `rLegumes` from `Gen Legumes` to `Gen Proteins`. It'll always generate one of the values `L WhiteBeans`, `L RedBeans`, `L Lentils`, or `L Chickpeas`.

By using `oneof`, you compose the two specialised generators to a more complex one that randomly selects one of those generators to generate a value.

Comment: Thanks for showing me `fmap`, it is indeed cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Proteins` data type doesn't actually contain any `AnimalProteins` or `Legumes`! Yes, you've named the *constructors* of `Proteins` the same way, but constructors live in the term language, not in the type language, so the compiler doesn't automatically associate them to the `AnimalProteins` *type*.

To do that, you need to be explicit:

```
data Proteins = AnimalProteins AnimalProteins | Legumes Legumes
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Unfortunately, I've added the other answer as it helped me to write a cleaner code in the end.